# How we handle input validation on python

Tags: python, validation, try-catch

I am new to python. I am wondering how we handle input validation using try catch. I have the code below, would you provide some suggestion?

```
 try:
    validate_input(date, value, region)
    raise IllegalArgumentError("Invalid input")

    except IllegalArgumentError as error:
         print("Invalid input occur:", error)



class IllegalArgumentError(ValueError):
    pass

def validate_input(date, value, region):
    if ((date is not None and date != "") and (value is not None and value != "") and
        (region is not None and region != "")):
        return True
    else:
       raise IllegalArgumentError("Invalid lambda event parameters")
```

Comment: everything looks ok, but why are you rasing error in except section ?

Comment: I don't familiar with python syntax. Does it look OK to return true or raise exception inside validate_input? How should I fix this code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's ok to return true and raise an exception. for neater code, you can remove the else part since the control flow will raise the exception if it's true.
However to catch the exception you need to mention after except keyword

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. What do you mean after the except keyword? Would you provide a code example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ```class CustomError(Exception):
  pass

try:
  # some code that may raise a custom error
  raise CustomError("This is a custom error.")
except CustomError as error:
  # handle the custom error
  print("Custom error occurred:", error)```

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited above code, does it look good now/.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestions

- First of all, you cannot call a function before it being actually created.
- Also, `except` is used to provide a set of code if the execution flow of code is interrupted with an error, so the raising of another error inside the `except` is illogical
- You need to use a base exception to create a custom exception

#### Will provide two ways on how I would have done this

1. 

```py
class IllegalArgumentError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, err):
        self.err = err
        super().__init__(self.err)
    
def validate_input(date, value, region):
    if ((date is not None and date != "") and (value is not None and value != "") and
        (region is not None and region != "")):
        return True
    else:
        raise IllegalArgumentError("Invalid lambda event parameters")
date = input()
value = input()
region = input()
validate_input(date,value,region)
```

2. 

```py
import sys
def validate_input(date, value, region):
    if ((date is not None and date != "") and (value is not None and value != "") and
        (region is not None and region != "")):
        return True
    else:
        raise ValueError
       
try:
    date = input()
    value = input()
    region = input()
    validate_input(date, value, region)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("Invalid lambda event parameters")
```

Hope this helps!